# Django - How to save "Google Maps Polygon" to Model?

Tags: javascript, python, django, google-maps, polygon

I want to create a polygon on Googlemaps, which should be posted to my postgres-database using Django/GeoDjango.

User select their area via Google Maps, Polygon should be saved.
i want to todo calculations on these Polygons.
On the other hand, other polygons should be displayed on the map.

I think, I have to use ajax/jquery but yes, im a django noob. :D

(Sorry for my English)

**Model**

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models

class Area(models.Model):
owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
poly = models.PolygonField()
objects = models.GeoManager()
```

**Views.py**

```
@csrf_protect
def create_area(request):
if request.user.is_authenticated():
    return render(request, 'basics/map_claim.html')
```

**GoogleMaps.js**

```js
<script>


 var map;
 var marker;
    var polygon;
 var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850);
 var geocoder;
 var infowindow;
    var polypoints=[];


 function initialize() {
     geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder()
   var mapProp = {
     center:myCenter,
     zoom:2,
     mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    mapTypeControl: false,
        panControl:false,
        rotateControl:false,
    mapTypeControl:true,
        streetViewControl: false
    };
    marker=null;

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-container"),mapProp);
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
            polypoints.push(event.latLng);
            placePolygon();
            console.log(polypoints);
    });
 }


    function placePolygon(){
        if(polygon){
            polygon.setPaths(polypoints);
        }
        else {
                polygon=new google.maps.Polygon({
                paths: polypoints,
                strokeColor: '#FF0000',
                strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                strokeWeight: 3,
                fillColor: '#FF0000',
                fillOpacity: 0.35,
                editable: true
            });
        } polygon.setMap(map);
    }

 function getLocation() {
     if (navigator.geolocation) {
         navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
     } else {
         x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported";
         y.innerHTML = "by this browser.";
     }
 }

 function showPosition(position) {
     var latlng={lat: parseFloat(position.coords.latitude), lng: parseFloat(position.coords.longitude)};
     placeMarker(latlng);
 }


 function placeMarker(location) {
     if(marker){
         infowindow.close();
         marker.setPosition(location);
         geocoder.geocode({'location': location}, function(results, status){
             infowindow.setContent(results[0].formatted_address);
             infowindow.open(map,marker);
         })
     }
     else{
         marker = new google.maps.Marker({
         position: location,
         map: map,
         });
         geocoder.geocode({'location': location}, function(results, status){
             infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: results[0].formatted_address});
             infowindow.open(map,marker);
         })
         map.setZoom(6);
     }
  map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
 }
 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $('#location-map-modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function(e) {
        initialize();
    });

</script>
```

Thank you for everything. :/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% I understand what you're asking, but the typical way to do that will be this:

```
area = Area()
area.owner = request.User
area.poly = polygon_data # Assumes you have a variable set to your polygon data
area.objects = object_data # Assumes you have a variable set to your geo object data
area.save()
```

That should create the instance and save it to your database. You can check if it saved by:

```
if not area.ID:
    # Oh noes, didn't save.
```

There's a TON of documentation on how django ORM works out there. I'd recommend reading some of that.

Comment: Okay. Ehm. How can i convert this googlemaps-Polygon to a geodjango polygon?

Comment: Now there's one I can't answer, but you might find some useful information here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/98074/how-to-use-google-maps-projection-with-geodjango-postgis

Googling around is also likely to get you some answers on that one.

Comment: Raider, hi! I need help with GMap.. please, connect with me via skype - denism2009... thanks a lot in advance!!!